# SQL statement not being correctly populated from DetailsView (ASPX/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, dataview

I've got the following code in an ASPX page:

```
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ChangeID,Completed" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" Height="50px" 
            Width="125px">
            <Fields>
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Completed" HeaderText="Completed" 
                    SortExpression="Completed" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Properties %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ATI_CHANGE_REQUESTS] WHERE ([ChangeID] = @ChangeID)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE ATI_CHANGE_REQUESTS SET Completed = @Completed WHERE ChangeID = @ChangeID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="grdRequests" Name="ChangeID" 
            PropertyName="SelectedDataKey[1]" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Completed" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ChangeID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And it appears, for the most part, to work correctly. It pulls the correct ChangeID from the gridview I referenced in the ControlParameter, but it never actually updates anything. SQL Profiler shows the command it executes as `UPDATE ATI_CHANGE_REQUESTS SET Completed=0 WHERE ChangeID=53` when I've got the row with ChangeID 53 seleced, but whether the checkbox in DetailsView4 is checked or not, it always sets Completed=0. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my SQL Data Source was hosed for some unknown reason, recreating SqlDataSource1 completely fixed the problem and I still have no idea why. Thanks anyway :)